# I need to select data which contains multiple if statements but data from only one if statement should be shown

Tags: php, mysql

select * from if($personname AND !$fname AND !$surname) then select * from user where name='$personname',
if($personname AND $fname AND !$surname) then select * from user where name='$personname' AND fname='$fname',
if($personname AND !$fname AND $surname) then select * from user where name='$personname' AND surname='$surname',
if($personname AND $fname AND $surname) then select * from user where name='$personname' AND fname=$fname AND surname='$surname',

if(!$personname AND $fname AND !$surname) then select * from user where fname='$fname',
if(!$personname AND $fname AND $surname) then select * from user where fname='$fname' AND surname='$surname',

if(!$personname AND !$fname AND $surname) then select * from user where surname='$surname', ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset"

Comment: so, what is the issue?

Comment: Is it correct? This is just a rough code I have written down. I don't even know if it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them like this:

```
$query = '';
if($personname AND !$fname AND !$surname) {
    $query = "select * from user where name='$personname'";

} elseif ($personname AND $fname AND !$surname) {
   $query = "select * from user where name='$personname'";
} // and so on...
```

so there will be only one `$query` after end of conditions

Comment: Are you talking about using php code if statements and then using mysql statements in it?

Comment: yes, it should be. Don't do that in `mysql` , it will be additional burden on database and not good practice

Comment: Okay, so I will have to make $query as a global variable so that it can be used outside the if statement, right?

Comment: Its working very fine. I wish I had taken help of stackoverflow early. This is a very useful website. Thank to @Jigar Shah